# Dynamic link to redirect to custom link when there is only an Android App and no Iphone app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using dynamic links to share user profiles in the app. Currently I have an:

1. Android App
2. Web Page for Desktops/Ios
3. No IOS App

In the manual creation of the dynamic link I have specified use cases for the following

- Launch activity on Android app else playstore
- Launch Web Page for Desktops
- Launch Web Page for Iphone and IPads

The first two use cases work well but for IPhones and Ipads it uses the deeplink and not the link for the web page set in the redirect link using ifl and ipfl as below

```
if (deepLink == null) {
    throw Exception("Invalid deep-link url.")
} else {
    link += "?link=$deepLink"
    if (androidId != null && androidId != "") {
        //redirect to playstore
        link += "&apn=" + packageName
    }
    link += "&st=" + "$nameShare's Profile"  //title
    link += "&sd=" + desigShare //description
    link += "&si" + "$profileImage" //Image
    //redirect to web page if link is opened on ios or ipad
    link += "&ifl=$redirectLink"
    link += "&ipfl=$redirectLink"
    //redirect to web page if on other platform other than ios and android
    link += "&ofl=$redirectLink"
}
```

How do I handle this error, as there is no IOS app but it is still using the deeplink and the the alternative redirect link specified in ifl. I also tried ius - didnt work

Also, the image is not loading in the preview.... the image size is less than required and dimension is 500X500

Any inputs will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this will take 5 minutes, use [branch.io](https://branch.io/) for links (you do not need to install the SDK)

- Signup create new app, write the name of the app
- got to "Configuration" from left menu select "I have an Android App"
- search for your app and select it then fill other options if you like
- it will give you a link "**https://[YOUR_APP_ID ].app.link**"
- use this link instead of the default link
- you can customize how the links will work perfectly

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi jabbar, Thanks but I am manually generating links using Firebase Dynamic links hence your solution will not work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid all ios and iPad params. as ifl & ipfl only works if you pass ios bundle id.

so to solve your problem.
Follow url as below.

```
https://your_subdomain.page.link/?link=your_deep_link&apn=package_name
```

Comment: so in this case if I remove ifl and ipfl - how will it redirect to specific domain?

Comment: ok, I removed ifl and ipfl and tested it, it only takes the dynamic link which leads to url not found.... whereas I need it to take the redirect link for IPhone and Ipad as there is no app and I need the user to go to a specific webpage to see the data at the link...

Comment: ?link should take to the deep link for ios and ipad.

Comment: I have a deeplink that redirects within the app on Android, it would do the same on Iphone but there is no Iphone app... and hence i need the redirect link (to go to website) to work on iphone...

Comment: Last thing you can try is pass 
ibi=package-name
isi=random-numbers like (4585565)
ifl=link-to-redirect